# Different way of writing expectation of function of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable. We can write its expectation as
$$ EX = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X > n).$$

Now, let $p\in (0,1)$ and then, 
$$ E(X^p) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^p P(X =n).$$

My question is, whether there exists a similar formula like the first one in this case, i.e.

$$ E (X^p) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \ ... P(X > n)\ ?$$

Edit: Or at least an inequality $E (X^p) \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \ ... P(X> n)$.

**Edit 2:** Specifically, assume $P(X>n ) \leq \frac{1}{n^{1/2}}$. I want to conclude that $$ EX^{p-\epsilon} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1/2+\delta}} P(X > n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1+\delta}} $$ holds true.

Comment: First, your first formula only works for **non-negative** r.v.'s... second... $$\mathbb{E}[X^p] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Pr(X^p > n)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Pr(X > n^{1/p})$$?

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a formula containing $P(X > n)$. So, from what you wrote I could follow using Markov's inequality: $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X > n^{1/p}) \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{EX}{n^{1/p}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^{-1/p} \ \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X > k).$$ But can I combine both sums?

Comment: The first sum is just a fixed number (depending on $p$), as it's a converging series -- if that helps. Also, reiterating the point: the whole thing is only true for non-negative $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $X \geq 0$, you can write
$$ \begin{align}
E[X] &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^p \Pr(X = n) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^p (\Pr(X>n-1)-\Pr(X>n)) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^p \Pr(X>n-1) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^p \Pr(X>n+1) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)^p \Pr(X>n) - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^p \Pr(X>n) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ((n+1)^p-n^p) \Pr(X>n) ,
\end{align}$$
where repeated adjustment has been done on the summation indices to make everything line up. As a check, putting $p=1$ gives $(n+1)^1-n^1 = 1 $, recovering the original formula.

---

Regarding the edit, we have by the MVT
$$ (n+1)^p-n^p = p\xi^{p-1} $$
for some $\xi$ between $n$ and $n+1$. In particular, it is smaller than $p(n+1)^{p-1}$, and for $n>0$, $(n+1)/n = 1+1/n \leq 2$, so we could say it is $\leq p2^{p-1}n^p$. Then if $\Pr(X>n) \leq n^q$, we have
$$ E[X^p] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ((n+1)^p-n^p) \Pr(X>n) \leq 1-\Pr(X=0)+p2^{p-1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{p+q-1} , $$
where we have separated off $n=0$ to avoid potential singularities.

Comment: Thanks, that's good but still not what I was looking for exactly. I will make an edit and explain in more detail what I am looking for.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Is this strong enough for what you want?

Comment: Yes, it is thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Suppose $X$ is non-negative. Use the identity
$$
X^p=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k^p-(k-1)^p) I(X\ge k).\tag{0}
$$
which is a telescoping sum where $I$ is the indicator function. At this point use the monotone convergence theorem to take expectations of both sides to yield
$$
EX^p=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k^p-(k-1)^p)P(X\geq k).\tag{1}
$$
With $p=2$ we obtain the special case
$$
EX^2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(2k-1)P(X\ge k).\tag{2}
$$
We can re-index (1) to obtain
$$
EX^p=\sum_{k=0}^\infty ((k+1)^p-k^p)P(X\geq k+1)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty ((k+1)^p-k^p)P(X>k).\tag{3}
$$
Note that (0) is a discrete analogue of the identity
$$
X^p=\int_{0}^\infty px^{p-1} I(X\geq x)\, dx.
$$